# Change button padding overwriting sass variables

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

I am trying to override the `btn-lg` padding on left and right by using sass pre-defined variables but unable to find the variable. All I could find was

```
.btn-lg {
  @include button-size($btn-padding-y-lg, $btn-padding-x-lg, $btn-font-size-lg, $btn-line-height-lg, $btn-border-radius-lg);
}
```

How can I change the left/right padding of btn-lg in bootstrap 4 by overriding sass variable in my custom SCSS file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find Bootstrap's variable defaults in *_variables.scss* file. The default variables used for `.btn-lg` is:

```
$btn-padding-y-lg:            $input-btn-padding-y-lg !default;
$btn-padding-x-lg:            $input-btn-padding-x-lg !default;
$btn-font-size-lg:            $input-btn-font-size-lg !default;
$btn-line-height-lg:          $input-btn-line-height-lg !default;

$input-btn-padding-y-lg:      .5rem !default;
$input-btn-padding-x-lg:      1rem !default;
```

To change the padding of `.btn-lg`, you need to override the default values of `$input-btn-padding-y-lg` and `$input-btn-padding-x-lg` in your *custom.scss* file. Remember that your overrides must come **before** you import Bootstrap's Sass files.

For example, to reduce the padding of `.btn-lg`, I would put this in my *custom.scss* file:

```
// Variable overrides
$input-btn-padding-y-lg:      0.2rem;
$input-btn-padding-x-lg:      0.5rem;

// Import Bootstrap and its defaults
@import "../bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was really helpful

Comment: You're welcome @zinnira. Can you please accept the answer if it solves your problem? Thank you.